# RedisConnectionException: It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s); ConnectTimeout

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I have seen various questions regarding this error but couldn't find any relevant solution.

I am using **stackexchange.redis.strongname** assembly version **1.2.6.0** for connecting to **redis server version 3.2.10** and randomly facing this RedisConnectionException.
Our architecture is web farm architecture hosted over AWS and sometimes one machine is not able to connect to redis server but the other one works fine. So this gives us surety that redis server is up and working fine. Also we tried to connect using redis-cli.exe when one machine is not able to connect and it works fine without any issues.

I am sharing the complete exception below:

```
[RedisConnectionException: It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s); ConnectTimeout]

    [RedisConnectionException: No connection is available to service this operation: EVAL; It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s); ConnectTimeout; IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=2,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=767,Free=32000,Min=2,Max=32767), Local-CPU: n/a]
       StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl(Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) +4657
       StackExchange.Redis.RedisBase.ExecuteSync(Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) +122
       StackExchange.Redis.RedisDatabase.ScriptEvaluate(String script, RedisKey[] keys, RedisValue[] values, CommandFlags flags) +142
       Microsoft.Web.Redis.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Eval>b__3() +56
       Microsoft.Web.Redis.StackExchangeClientConnection.RetryForScriptNotFound(Func`1 redisOperation) +135
       Microsoft.Web.Redis.StackExchangeClientConnection.RetryLogic(Func`1 redisOperation) +144
       Microsoft.Web.Redis.StackExchangeClientConnection.Eval(String script, String[] keyArgs, Object[] valueArgs) +542
       Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisConnectionWrapper.TryTakeWriteLockAndGetData(DateTime lockTime, Int32 lockTimeout, Object& lockId, ISessionStateItemCollection& data, Int32& sessionTimeout) +262
       Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider.GetItemFromSessionStore(Boolean isWriteLockRequired, HttpContext context, String id, Boolean& locked, TimeSpan& lockAge, Object& lockId, SessionStateActions& actions) +1160
       Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider.GetItemExclusive(HttpContext context, String id, Boolean& locked, TimeSpan& lockAge, Object& lockId, SessionStateActions& actions) +211
       System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.GetSessionStateItem() +176
       System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.BeginAcquireState(Object source, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +1018
       System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +710
       System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +634
```

Here is the code which I am using for creating connection to redis server

```
var configOptions = new StackExchange.Redis.ConfigurationOptions
{
   ConnectTimeout = 5000,
   ConnectRetry = 5,
   SyncTimeout = 5000,
   AbortOnConnectFail = false,
};

configOptions.EndPoints.Add(host, port);

var conn = StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(configOptions);
return conn;
```

Can anyone help me to find out the root cause for this issue or some steps to debug it would also be of great help.

Comment: Have to check the Inbound and outbound Rules?

Comment: If there is any problem in the rules then it will not connect permanently. The issue occurs only once or twice a day.